# Solve Limit on Process.Start() characters

Tags: c#, wpf, email, process

I am trying to pass multiple email-adresses to my mail-client (tried Thunderbird and Windows 10s integrated Mail-app). Unfortunately there seems to be a limit on the Process.Start() command (~2000 characters). Heres my simple testcode written in visual studio as a WPF-application:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string mail = "mailto:test@test.com?subject=BlaBla&bcc=";
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            mail = mail + "test@test.com" + i + ",";       
        }
        Process.Start("mailto: "+mail);

    }
```

Its working fine until the 125th adress while it should pass 1000 adresses in my test.
Is there a workaround or a completly different solution to overcome my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just do a new process per 1000 mail messages? That.... or you could use exchange to send emails.

Comment: This will open a new mailclient-window (= write a new mail), while i want all recipients going to a single e-mail.

Comment: Write emails to a file and pass the filename to your app

Comment: @Eser: could you give an example? Im not sure how to use the content of a textfile as command line arguments in Windows (or maybe i missunderstood your solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the "UseShellExecute = false;" option from "ProcessStartInfo". This invokes createprocess() which allows for 32767 characters in the command line. I read thats its not the best practice but it works for me.
You have to give the full path with deactivated UseShellExecute, for example:

```
string mail = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)") + "\\Mozilla Thunderbird\\thunderbird.exe";
```